# Parsing nested objects in JSON objects into multiple, cleaner JSON objects in Python

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a best practice for parsing messy JSON objects that have nested objects such that they're stored more cleanly?

I'm wondering if I could use Pyspark to solve this problem

I first extracted the information and loaded it to a s3 bucket, then I used a get function on s3 .Bucket('bucket-name').Object('json-file-name') to load the data.

An example would be trying to find the artist name and the song name (Polo G and RAPSTAR) here:
[image]

Comment: can you provide some data of you nested JSON, like a couple of lines, also what results you want a flatten JSON ?

Comment: offtopic Q.  Before landing to use Pyspark, these questions will help you identify whether you need Pyspark or other tools could better fit. 1) What is the your size of a JSON file? 2) How many JSON files that you need to process? 3) What output do you expect to write back (filetype, #of files, shape of the JSON content)?

Comment: @Sec147 can you add real data and not a picture of the data please.